# Sentences as documents in Nutch

Tags: search, lucene, indexing, web-crawler, nutch

I need Nutch to split web pages into sentences when saving the crawl results. The reason is so that Solr sees each sentence as a document when indexing.

The result I need is to be able to do a search for, say, "one word" and get a list of all sentences that contain "one" and/or "word".

I'm new to Nutch so some pointers would really be useful...

1. Should I look into Nutch configuration files?
2. Do I need to change Nutch source code?
3. Or can I write a separate app that can edit the crawl results once Nutch is done crawling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can check out Nutch for your task.

1) configuration files alone will not do the job for you. see points above.

2) you'd need to write your own Parser plugin that hooks to nutch parsing phase after crawls, split your HTMLpage into sentences and return N results from a single page. This is quite odd as usually one page is one result. Check out the FeedParser to see how to return multiple results from one page.

3) in principle, you could iterate over the pages fetched by nutch, get the text, split them in sentences and use SOLR api to index your sentences as if they were docs. this could even be a mapreduce job quite easily.

As a general reference I suggest you have a look at this article for splitting your text in sentences:

http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/04/uima-sentence-annotator-using-opennlp.html